# Can I cross the Albania/Greece border on foot?

Tags: international-travel, borders, albania, greece, hitchhiking

I intend to cross from Albania to Greece at the Konispol/Sagiada border crossing. I will be hitchhiking so I will sometimes be in a car, and sometimes on foot.

Now I did walk across the Montenegro/Albania border but I know that it is not legal to walk across the Greece/Turkey border.

So does Greece have the same problem with its Albanian border as its Turkish border. Can I walk across or will I have to ensure I find a car who doesn't mind taking a passenger through the border checkpoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My hostel owner here in Albania assures me I can walk across.

Last night I walked across the southernmost border crossing from Albania to Greece on the Konispol-Sagiada route with absolutely no problems at 8pm Albanian time, 9pm Greek time.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of months ago i crossed the Albanian-Greek border not at Konispol/Sagiada, but another one. It worked out fine, so i guess there shouldn't be a problem for other border crossings from Albania to Greece.

Comment: +1. In August I crossed from Greece to Albania at [Kakavia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakavia_(border_crossing)) on foot; no problems. (Curiously, I was approached by guys eagerly selling their (overpriced) taxi/minibus services even before getting from the border zone properly to the Albanian side.)